# Sort a listed with deep nested arrays

Tags: java, java-8

I have following layout of classes that I'm trying to sort.

```
Class C
{
    string name;
    int val;
}

Class B
{
   some B fields;
    C[] cs; 
}

Class A
{
    some A fields; 
    B[] bs;
}
```

I have to sort `List<A>` based on C val.  The condition is
`A1's B1's C1[n].name == A2's B2's C2[n] == "John"`
then compare  and return

```
C1[n].value > C2[n].value
```

I tried this but it says I trying to sort Cs not A's

```
List<A> listA = {// full initialized with all the values}
List<A> sortedA = listA.stream()
            .flatMap(blist -> Arrays.asList(listA.getBs()).stream())
            .flatMap(clist -> Arrays.asList(blist.getCs()).stream())
            .sorted((c1,c2) -> {
                 if (c1.getName().equals(c2.getName()).compareTo("John") {
                        return c1.getVal() > c2.getVal()
                    })
```

****Update with sample input and expected output****

```
list<A> list = { A2, A1, A3}
A2{
        some A2 fields; 
        B2[] b2s;  //array of B2 objects
}
B2 {
        some B2 fields; 
        C2[] c2s;  //array of C2 objects
}
C2 = { (John, 50), (xyz, 25)}

A1{
... B1[] b1s
}
B1 {
.... C1[] c1s
}
C1 = {(abc,55),(John,30)}

A3{
... B3[] b3s
}
B3 {
.... C3[] c3s
}
C3 = {(John,40),(def,35)}
```

before sorted: `list<A> list = { A2, A1, A3}`
After sorted: `list<A> sortedList = { A1, A3, A2}`
i.e. based on their John's age in their Cs

```
A1.C1.John.age (30) A3.C3.John.age(40) A2.C2.John.age(50)
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough for me. First of all, your `A` objects is having multiple `C` objects. If you want to sort `A`s, you may need to make comparison between `A`s, i.e. compare multiple `C`s to multiple `C`s. Second, your code under `sorted` seems cut.

Comment: Could you add an example for input and expected output?

Comment: My bad forgot about the input/output. I have updated with sample. New to Java 8.  Thanks for help!

Comment: Sorting requires a defined order for all elements. You can not define an order for only some of the elements (matching a condition) when you want to sort.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to sort multiple times but do not put in the full sort criteria.

First create a comparator that can tell you the sort order for two elements:

```
public class AComparator implements Comparator<A> {
    public int compare​(A a1, A a2) {
        // this is too simple as we do not look at null values or empty arrays
        return a1.bs[0].cs[0].name.compareTo(a2.bs[0].cs[0].name);
    }
}
```

Then use that comparator to sort your initial list:

```
List<A> list = // wherever you initialize this from 
Collections.sort(list, new AComparator());
```

See also:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)